# Linearly polarised Electromagnetic waves

Tags: systems-of-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

**Question:** Define the linearly polarised electromagnetic wave with electric field given by,

$$E = A   \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a \cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x_1-\frac{{x_3}{{}}}2-ct) \\
0  \\
\sqrt{3} \cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x_1-\frac{{x_3}{{}}}2-ct) \end{array} \right)
$$

Where A is a given constant. Find the dimnesionless factor a.

**My attempt:**

I'm not quite sure what this question is asking me to do.

I know we can write a linearly polarised EM wave as:

$$E(x,t)= \epsilon .sin(K.x - ct)$$

where $\epsilon$ is a constant vector satisfying $\epsilon.K=0$

Therefore I can say that in this case, $K= (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0,-\frac{1}{2})$

But how would I find a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ${\bf E}$ is an electromagnetic wave that it should be a solution to Maxwell's equations; in particular, ${\bf E}$ should be divergenceless: $\nabla \cdot {\bf E}=0$ for all $x_{i}$ and $t$. This should be enough to find $a$.